# Using grunt rev on views in javascript files

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I am having an issue where the browser is caching the views specified in my angularjs app. The view paths are coded into the app.js file. Is there a way to use grunt usemin/rev on javascript files in order to update these references with a versioned files?

Comment: Still haven't figured out?

Comment: Check out grunt-angular-templates grunt task. It's solves this issue nicely